# Brownie, Where do I put my Infura API Key... not The ID, The Actual Key?

Tags: infura, brownie

I am learning how to us [brownie for NFTs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p36tXHX1JD8) and I don't know where to put my infura API Key. I see in the Github repo that the .env file looks like this:

```
export PRIVATE_KEY=asafdagadd
export WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID=asdfsdf
```

But where does the API key go? Just the ID won't let me make API calls right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brownie actually has infura built in, so you only need the `WEB3_INFURA_PROJECT_ID` and brownie will sort all the URLs and such under the hood.

Test it out and see what happens!

Comment: It failed with this error "HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/<myprojectId>" but that was what I predicted. My Infura API needs the Secret Key right? Otherwise it would be a big security vulnerability because anyone could make an API request to my Infura project if they knew the project ID right?

Comment: Oh nevermind it worked! From what I researched the problem was that Infura only lets you make API calls for 1 smart contract to each Infura project. I had already used the last project for another smart contract. I made a new Infura project and used the new project ID. Btw, I feel like that's a security vulnerability that I don't have to put my Infura secret in a post request to make API calls.

Comment: Potentially, you can alternatively always run your own ETH node if you prefer!